# Программа выдает ошибку при применении метода replaceFirst

Tags: java, replace

Почему этот код вызывает ошибку?

```
String word = "( h";
String text = word.replaceFirst("(", "");
```

А если написать вот так, то ошибки не будет:

```
String word = "( h";
String text = word.replace("(", "")
```

Почему replaceFirst так реагирует на скобку и выдает вот такую ошибку?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')'
)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1969)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1706)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1352)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2178)
at com.company.Main.encode(Main.java:20)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: Попробуйте экранировать скобочку, `\(`

Comment: Под капотом Pattern, видимо дело в этом. В первом случае, думает что регулярка должна залететь, во втором поток chars.

Comment: tym32167, дело в том, что я использую метод replaceFirst в цикле. Есть возможность как-то обойти эту проблему, используя цикл? Вот сам код:

String word = "( h";
for (String elem:word.split("")) {
    text = word.replaceFirst(elem, "");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Есть возможность как-то обойти эту проблему, используя цикл?*

Для экранирования *всех* символов в строке, которая используется в качестве регулярного выражения, существует метод [`Pattern::quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)), который превращает входную строку в строковый литерал.

Если входная строка гарантированно не содержит последовательности в виде:

- `\Q` - начало экранирования
- `\E` - конец экранирования,
  то грубая реализация подобного метода может выглядеть так:

```java
public static String quoteRegex(String literal) {
    return "\\Q" + literal + "\\E";
}
```

Таким образом, код для замены будет выглядеть так:

```java
String word = "( h"; 
for (String elem:word.split("")) { 
    text = word.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(elem), "");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот ответ решил мою проблему!